# Java / Eclipse one class over multiple files

Tags: java, eclipse, class

Is it possible to have a single class over multiple files ?

I have a Database class that extends SQLLiteOpenHelper
currently around 3030 lines
Everytime I restart eclipse

I get Failed to create the part's controls

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 51
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at com.cb.eclipse.folding.java.calculation.UserDefinedRegionHelper.isSentinel(UserDefinedRegionHelper.java:53)
    at com.cb.eclipse.folding.java.calculation.UserDefinedRegionHelper.isOpeningSentinel(UserDefinedRegionHelper.java:29)
    at com.cb.eclipse.folding.java.calculation.CommentHelper.isUserDefinedSentinel(CommentHelper.java:90)
    at com.cb.eclipse.folding.java.calculation.CommentHelper.handle(CommentHelper.java:67)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure you need to extend it? What do you what to achieve?

Comment: you have index out of range, something in your code is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to do some re-design. You cannot have one class over multiple files, but you can redesign one class into multiple classes.

Answer (score 2):

No, consider refacturing it into multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

You have two tools here to help you - composition and inheritance.

Look at all the functionality within your monster class and consider what is the best way to separate it out into their a super class or a component class. Look at what will be the best way to allow you to re-use the code in future. What will group similar concepts together, etc.